# 18 teams play against 8 teams each...

Tags: combinatorics

So, this is a combinatorics problem that's given me quite a few struggles for a while now. It goes like this:

There are $18$ teams in a football championship, every team played against exactly $8$ other teams. Prove that there are $3$ teams such that there are no teams which have played against each other among them. (we should prove that there are some teams that if we pick e.g. $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$, then $a_1$ didn't face $a_2$, $a_1$ didn't face $a_3$, and $a_2$ didn't face $a_3$).

I really have no idea how to even start the problem. I've tried to make contradiction, but don't know what the hypothesis should be. I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks.

EDIT: I've tried to prove that among every three teams, there's at least one pair that faced each other. There are $18\choose 3$ ways to take 3 teams, so every pair appears in 16 groups. In each of these tuples though, we can say that $a_1$ faced every third element in first 8 groups and $a_2$ faced the reamining 8. I know this is probably wrong way to go about it, but I got stuck at here.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to explain how you tried to obtain a contradiction.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The way "There are ${18\choose 3}=816$ $3$-teams triangles, but only $\frac{8\cdot 18}{2}$ games, each within exactly $16$ of the triangles" you don't arrive a contradiction as $\frac{8\cdot 18}{2}\cdot 16 = 1152>816 = {18\choose 3}$.

Comment: What would be the right way to solve it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false.
Consider the counter-example: teams $1$-$9$ played only with each other and teams $10$-$18$ played only with each other too. Either way you select $3$ teams there will be at least $2$ of them in the $1$-$9$ half or in the $10$-$18$ half, so you can't form a triangle with no edges in this case.

Comment: Thanks very much! I didn't get your initial comment, sorry for that. Now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: There was no this solution in that comment. You can press the edit button on the answer to see how did I arrive at the contradiction. No problem. )